# Raspberry Pi Dashcam feed cable through closed car door?

Tags: camera, cable

weird question, i am sure but there is a good reason.

We have a bike rack at the back of our van and when we drive I see poorly out the back. I have to use the side mirrors when of course the middle mirror gives much better view of what is behind.

I would like to create a Raspberry Pi Rear DashCam of what is behind but the first problem I see is that of cabling.
I would like to position the camera on the last bike. I would like to feed a cable from this camera into the van through the back door.

My question (at last..)  is there a suitable cable to do this ?

It would of course be very flat and would not be affected by the closed door.

Thanks

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer. I am not sure. 
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2144
I will investigate further.

Comment: Ah, the ribbon cable is very delicate and brittle.  I once played with car parking cameras and remember they are using composite video cables.  They shop also give me drilling bits to drill small holes and big 10~12mm holes to house the camera. So my stupid suggestion is drilling a hole on the roof top.  A not too stupid suggestion is to use a WiFi guy like ESP8266, sitting with Rpi, on rooftop.

Comment: good idea about the ESP8266 on the roof .... could use a small windmill generator of some kind to keep the batteries charged whenever the vehicle is moving

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.